# How to remove entries in matrix which are more than a threshold

Tags: r

my matrix looks like this:

```
> ld1
           rs11721 rs3813199 rs3766186 rs7515488 rs6675798   rs6603785 rs11804831 rs11260930 rs221035 rs221045 rs2132851 rs12751725
rs3813199    0.565     1.000     0.988     0.567     0.448     0.351      0.160      0.003    0.001    0.001     0.001      0.001
rs3766186    0.553     0.988     1.000     0.560     0.438     0.343      0.155      0.003    0.001    0.001     0.001      0.001
rs7515488    0.447     0.567     0.560     1.000     0.565     0.595      0.342      0.003    0.000    0.000     0.000      0.000
rs6675798    0.494     0.448     0.438     0.565     1.000     0.752      0.383      0.000    0.000    0.000     0.000      0.000
rs6603785    0.544     0.351     0.343     0.595     0.752     1.000      0.454      0.000    0.000    0.000     0.000      0.000
rs11804831   0.289     0.160     0.155     0.342     0.383     0.454      1.000      0.002    0.001    0.001     0.001      0.001
rs11260930   0.000     0.003     0.003     0.003     0.000     0.000      0.002      1.000    0.284    0.284     0.243      0.243
rs221035     0.001     0.001     0.001     0.000     0.000     0.000      0.001      0.284    1.000    1.000     0.856      0.856
```

How do I remove all entries in this matrix which are more than 0.95 but not equal 1? So I would keep all less than 0.95 and all those equal 1.

I tried this:

```
md1 <- ld1[ld1[, ] <0.95, ]
```

But it didn't remove entries which are more than 0.95

I would like to remove those entries not just replace them with NA.

Comment: Try `ld1[ld1 < 0.95]`. This is indexing with a logical matrix.

Comment: Use `ld1[ld1 < 0.95] <- NA`

Comment: @RuiBarradas your solution will produce a matrix of T/F

Comment: @akash87 Or `is.na(ld1) <- ld1 > 0.95`.

Comment: @akash87 No, the index is a matrix of T/F,  but the result of indexing the original `ld1` by that logical matrix is not. The problem with my first solution is that it returns a vector, not a matrix.

Comment: What do you intend to do with values that are above that threshold? Replace with `NA`? Or remove them, thereby changing the dimensions of the matrix?

Comment: I would like to remove them if possible

Comment: @anikaM, in R a true `NA` value signifies missing data. What exactly do you mean by remove? Remove any column / row that contains an `NA`?

Comment: the dimension of the matrix would change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution by creating a function that does what you want then using apply to run it over all matrix elements.

```
remove_95 = function(x){
  ifelse(x > 0.95, NA, x)
}

apply(ld1, c(1,2), FUN = remove_95)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: do you know how I would remove those entries not just replace them with NA?

Comment: What do you mean by "remove"? In R, NA is the definition of empty. You can substitute NA by whatever you want, just adjust the function

Answer (score 1):

If you want to repace with `NA` this should suffice:

```
set.seed(1)
ld1 <- matrix(sample(1:1000, 81, replace = T)/1000, 9, 9)
diag(ld1) <- 1


ld1[ld1 > .95 & ld1 < 1] <- NA
ld1
       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9]
 [1,] 1.000 0.062 0.381 0.383 0.795 0.790 0.071 0.333 0.347
 [2,] 0.373 1.000 0.778 0.870 0.108 0.024 0.100 0.651 0.334
 [3,] 0.573 0.177 1.000 0.341 0.724 0.478 0.317 0.259 0.477
 [4,] 0.909 0.688 0.213 1.000 0.412 0.733 0.519 0.479 0.893
 [5,] 0.202 0.385 0.652 0.600 1.000 0.693 0.663 0.767 0.865
 [6,] 0.899 0.770 0.126 0.494 0.648 1.000 0.407 0.085 0.390
 [7,] 0.945 0.498 0.268 0.187 0.783 0.862 1.000 0.876 0.778
 [8,] 0.661 0.718 0.387 0.828 0.554 0.439 0.294 1.000    NA
 [9,] 0.630    NA 0.014 0.669 0.530 0.245 0.460 0.840 1.000
```

If you want to remove columns *and* rows that contain any value > .95 this should suffice. Although, it would work if you just removed columns or rows. If this is not what you are looking for can you post your expected output:

```
remove_me <- which(ld1 > .95 & ld1 < 1, arr.ind = T)
ld1[-remove_me[,1], -remove_me[,2]]

      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]
[1,] 1.000 0.381 0.383 0.795 0.790 0.071 0.333
[2,] 0.373 0.778 0.870 0.108 0.024 0.100 0.651
[3,] 0.573 1.000 0.341 0.724 0.478 0.317 0.259
[4,] 0.909 0.213 1.000 0.412 0.733 0.519 0.479
[5,] 0.202 0.652 0.600 1.000 0.693 0.663 0.767
[6,] 0.899 0.126 0.494 0.648 1.000 0.407 0.085
[7,] 0.945 0.268 0.187 0.783 0.862 1.000 0.876
```

EDIT: updated answer and example assuming it is a correlation matrix with 1.000 on the main diagonal. I also assumed there would be no perfect correlations aside from the main diagonal.

Comment: Hi I tried running this last code you posted and it removed everything. Can you please double check

Comment: @anikaM, can you post your expected output as an edit to your question? I am not clear what you mean by remove / the dimensions would change.

Comment: HI Andrew, I figured how to do this by doing melting, it made it more easier to see and understand what is going on

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with melting the matrix:

```
library(reshape2)
ld1$snp1 <- rownames(ld1)
m = melt(ld1, id.vars = "snp1", value.name = "r2",variable.name = "snp2")

> head(m)
       snp1    snp2    r2
1   rs11721 rs11721 1.000
2 rs3813199 rs11721 0.565
3 rs3766186 rs11721 0.553
4 rs7515488 rs11721 0.447
5 rs6675798 rs11721 0.494
6 rs6603785 rs11721 0.544
# find teh subset which to extract from the m data frame
r1=m[m$r2 > .95 & m$snp1 != m$snp2,]
d=setdiff(m,r1)
```